# Book cataloguing from commandline

Tags: command-line, information-management

I have many books both digital and physical, I want to catalogue them and tag them. I also need to search books based on tags or titles. Suggest ideal cli application to achieve this.
**OS:** Linux or Windows
Java/Python based apps are welcome.
Free or Moderate price software.

Comment: Can't do that without knowing what OS it should run on, if there's a price limit, if Java/Python based solutions are acceptable, what search criteria must be supported … and what you feel "ideal".

Comment: I have edited my answer based on your comment @Izzy

Comment: Thanks! Now it just lacks the search criteria it must support :) Just tags and titles – no authors, release date or anything else? Especially, no contents?

Comment: Hm, looks my favorite candidate might match that: Calibre has [search support](https://manual.calibre-ebook.com/generated/en/calibredb.html#search). It comes with a GUI as well (which might be easier for cataloging). But you can [add books](https://manual.calibre-ebook.com/generated/en/calibredb.html#add) from cli as well. Would that fit you?

Answer (score 1):

The simplest approach to this is to write a text file with one line per book. You can then use `grep` to search for books from the command line.